# Internet Radio stuck in "Contacting tuning service"

Tags: macos, itunes, itunes-radio

I have iTunes 12.8 on High Sierra. I selected Internet Radio from the Library sidebar, but the list of stations is empty. At the top it's stuck saying "Contacting tuning service... Refreshing category list".

Comment: See https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/itunes/listen-to-internet-radio-itns2946/mac

Comment: That's what I did, and that's when it gets stuck.

Comment: What about https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8070788?answerId=32269965022#32269965022

Comment: I already did that. I edited the sidebar to add Internet Radio, but when I go to it nothing shows and it says it's trying to connect.

Comment: check your WiFi and make sure you leave it for a while

Comment: WiFi is fine, I'm listening to stations that I already have in my playlists. I just can't find new stations to add to my library.